# Unfamiliar prime-generating polynomials related to Heegner numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, quadrics

I just stumbled on a set of prime-generating polynomials of the form $$9 n^2-3 H n+H (H+1)/4$$ (where $H$ is a Heegner number $>11$), which generate the same number of distinct primes as their more familiar counterparts. There is some overlap in the primes generated by $n^2 - n + 41$ and $9 n^2-489 n+6683$ for example, but they are not all the same.

Are these of any interest, and are there other prime-generating polynomials that are related directly to the Heegner numbers? Also, why are the coefficients $9$ and $3$ involved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number), 
Rabinowitz showed that $n^2 + n + p$ is prime for $n=0, \ldots, p-2$ iff $p = (1+H)/4$, $H$ a Heegner number.  If you substitute $n = 3 m - (H+1)/2$, you get your polynomial $9 m^2 - 3 H m + H(H+1)/4$.

Comment: true, but if I substitute $n$ for anything *other than* $3 m - (H+1)/2$, I don't get all prime values for $m=0 \ldots p-2$. Why these values in particular?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to generate an infinite number of prime generating polynomials with of course a fluctuating number of primes that was posted in the math stackexchange few months back.

Comment: could you please provide a link?

Comment: here it is:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220166/what-can-we-learn-from-prime-generating-polynomials

Comment: and in this link, we can even construct twin-prime generating quadratic polynomials.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223781/is-there-a-link-between-the-bunyakovsky-conjecture-and-the-twin-prime-conjecture